# How to use OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android without a display?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

I'm doing some image processing on Android just like [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) done on iOS.

My product is willing to support any platform. And, it can already run well with GLEW on PC.
And it can also run with a glSurfaceView on my Android device & Blue stacks.

But, the display is not neccessary since my interface is like: ProcessImage(Bitmap dst, Bitmap src, ...other args...);

So, my question is: How to use GLES without a display like glSurfaceView?

Here is what I do on PC:
call `wglMakeCurrent(the_dc_to_use, the_gl_rc_to_use)` before my job;
call `wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL)" after my job;`
And the context is created from my window's HWND.

What is the similar function on Android?

Comment: A point of note, `wglMakeCurrent (...)` does not create a context from your `HWND`. All it does is associate the `HGLRC` you pass (handle to an OpenGL context you already created) with the current thread and tells it to draw into your `HDC` (*effectively*, the client rectangle of your window).

Comment: I see, the usage of wgl* is clear for me. I just want to know, how to do such things on Android...

Comment: eglCreatePixmapSurface is what i want. So my problem is solved.

Comment: Make sure you write that as an answer and accept it, that is how Stack Overflow is supposed to work.